# Need help updating or finding a more suitable video driver for Toshiba Satellite L775

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, motherboard

I recently installed a new SSD in my Toshiba Satellite L775 laptop, just got Windows 7 (64 bit) up and running (clean install as my HDD died) and it seems to be functioning apart from the fact I can no longer access the resolutions I used to (1600x900 I think).

I don't want to download the driver from the Toshiba website as I had to get the motherboard replaced a few months ago, the original board had an integrated NVIDIA card, but the new one has a standard Intel card, so I doubt I can get the original drivers. As I recently had it replaced however I know the exact board currently in use, which is a...

Toshiba Satellite L775 Intel Laptop Motherboard s989 69N0Y3M1EB-01 H000032290

The driver I have is the "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" from Microsoft. The chipset is an Intel SandyBridge Mobile Graphics chipset. When I try to update this driver it says it is already up to date. A brief google search for drivers for this chipset returned [this result](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS019005), but 
I am scared to start testing random drivers in case I render my laptop unusable without a screen, so I was wondering if anyone was 100% sure this is the correct driver, and also how I go about changing it, do I uninstall the first driver first, or will running the driver installation make it replace the old driver?

Cheers!

Comment: Ah, satellite. "The Laptop From Hell". I have the exact same issue, exact same system, no working drivers found yet. Even the ones from their website do not seem to work. If you find one, Please let us know.

Comment: In the end the resolution sorted itself out after I downloaded a heap of Windows updates and restarted the laptop. So with the standard windows VGA graphics driver it can work fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted in the end. The Windows "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" Driver seems to be the correct one. After downloading some windows updates and restarting, the problem sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange the new motherboard doesn't ship with the NVidia GPU. However, the Intel GPU is integrated in the CPU, so it should be also present on the old motherboard.

The link you give is to another laptop manufacturer, which is not a good idea to take the driver from. It's better to search directly on the specific hardware manufacturer, here Intel.

Searching on the Intel website (Support → Downloads and Drivers → Browse for drivers,  then selecting Graphics → Laptop graphics drivers → 2nd Generation Intel Core…) I find this : https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23764